# In Realm Mobile Platform, how do I call self.realm.objects to List<Item>

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Im trying to work out how to call self.realm.objects(...) and assign to results: List.

There isn't anything for that it seems, but if I change my results to a Results, I can't append using an add method later on.

Not sure which way to proceed

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do? A `List<T>` is only useful as a property of a managed object. If you need to populate such a property, you should mutate it in place using `append(contentsOf:)` or `replaceSubrange(_:with:)` to append / replace objects from a `Results`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting a Results collection to List is really straightforward, you just call `List(results)` and you are left with a `List<T>` collection. You can also do `Array(results)` to get an array instead of a Realm list.

In context:

```
let realm = try! Realm()
let objects = realm.objects(MyObject.self)
let listOfObjects = List(objects)
```

Or you can do the last two steps in one line as well

`let objects = List(realm.objects(MyObject.self))`

Comment: This no longer works. Needs update